# Best Wireless Card for x64 version of Windows 7/Vista?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, pci

I'm currently using the Belkin F5D7000 PCI Wireless G Card, which I used with Windows XP just fine. I was even able to get it to work with Vista as described by the below link.

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2007/04/11/Windows-Vista-Device-Drivers-for-Belkin-F5D7000-Wireless-Network-Card.aspx

However, the work around I found to get it working with Vista doesn't really work that well with Windows 7 RTM. It works, but the network connection will be spotty and it makes it difficult to use. I also tried the driver from Belkin for Vista x64, but that didn't even work for me at all.

I would really like to find a Wireless Network Card that's compatible with Windows 7/Vista x64. Since I need to buy a new card, I'm strongly considering getting a Wireless N card (since it's faster and also supports Wireless G); however I really need a card that WORKS so I'm not too partial to only getting a Wireless G card.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Preferably Wireless N, but Wireless G would also be fine. Also, I'd prefer to get a PCI card instead of a USB dongle.

Comment: It's nice that nobody has commented yet... I have since purchased a long CAT6 cable and now have a wired connection. Any way it would probably be nice for someone else who finds this question while searching if others would post some kind of answer to help them out. I however gave up on wireless with my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a ton of Wireless Cards out there for desktops. You could get a USB Wireless Adapter, that would probably solve your issue. Although you said you purchased a network cable, that's probably the cheapest option if you are able to run the wire.